# как создать экземпляр Vue для элемента скрытого при помощи v-if?

Tags: vue.js

Есть `<div id="app">`, к нему привязан экземпляр `var a = new Vue({el: "#app", data: {canvasHidden: true}})`. Внутри #app элемента есть `<canvas id="layer0" v-if="!canvasHidden">`, к которому хочется привязать другой Vue.

Проблема в том, что когда в коде инициализируется `var b = new Vue({el: '#layer0'})`, `<canvas>` скрыт из DOM, и при присваивании `a.canvasHidden = false` холст не отображается.

Comment: Нужно вызывать функцию инициализации Vue уже после того, как показался холст. Т.е. сначала появился холст, потом задержка через `$nextTick` и только после этого вызывается код `new Vue({...})`.
По уму можно сделать это через `watch`.

Comment: @Idushii спасибо, нашел другой выход - вместо v-if навесить на canvas v-show, этот атрибут сохраняет в DOM, и управляет режимом отображения display: none

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант))